# Путь к файлам на локальном сервере

Tags: php, wordpress

При разработке приходится много тестировать и на локальном и на удалённом сервере, а пути к файлам и папкам различные на этих серверах. Допустим WP_PLUGIN_DIR или WP_PLUGIN_URL, или в wp_upload_dir() есть basedir и baseurl возвращают разные результаты, т.е. допустим на локальном сервере не работает путь, начинающийся с http.
Иногда путаю эти пути, и забываю поменять при переходе с локального на удалённый, потом трудно искать появляющиеся ошибки.
Подскажите, есть ли универсальное решение, чтобы можно было прописать один раз путь к файлам или папкам, чтобы одинаково работало на локальном и удалённом сервере?

Comment: НУ скажем конфигурационный файл или переменные окружения. Дёшево и сердито. К тому же проверено временем...

Comment: @Akina а можете показать пример?

Comment: А почему на локальном сервере не работает http? Какой же он тогда сервер...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константы и функции, содержащие _DIR предназначены для вывода **пути к папке** на сервере, неважно - локальном или удалённом.

Константы и функции, содержащие _URL, предназначены для вывода **url** (uniform resource locator) - Интернет адреса.

При правильном использовании этих сущностей - ничего в коде менять не надо при переносе сайта с локального сервера на удаленный.

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, допустим я пишу парсер изображений. Использую для копирования функцию copy. Как нужно указывать путь для сохранения на своём сервере? т.е. вы говорите, что есть два вида путей (_DIR, _URL), какой нужно указывать для сохранения изображения с сайта источника на свой сайт? 
допустим copy(sourceSite, destSite)

Comment: >При правильном использовании этих сущностей - ничего в коде менять не надо при переносе сайта с локального сервера на удаленный.

Comment: в каких случаях нужно указывать путь с .._DIR,  а в каких случая ..._URL ?

Comment: что-то у меня из-за этой путаницы много ошибок

Comment: вы же файл пишете файловыми операциями php: fopen, fclose, fwrite. Им, само собой, надо указывать файловые пути. Ну, например: `fopen( dirname(__FILE__) . '/cache/gmap.js')`

Comment: парсить картинки лучше с помощью fwrite ? А copy подойдёт?

Comment: Странный вопрос. Парсить надо парсером. А fwrite всего лишь пишет файл на диск. copy тоже оперирует только с файлами на сервере.

Comment: >Парсить надо парсером

Comment: в цикле допустим парсер берёт url картинки, теперь нужно скопировать картинку себе на сервер. Какую функцию лучше использовать: fwrite или copy ?

Comment: Можно и copy, она умеет открывать удаленные файлы, через url